# Printing out array in constructor coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

This should print out everything in collection
but it only prints out two elements.

Why won't it print out the entire list?
Is it some kind of race case?

http://jsfiddle.net/Czenu/1/

```
class window.Restful
  constructor:->
    _.each @collection, (action,kind)=>
      $('.actions').append "<div>#{action} #{kind}</div>"

class Material extends Restful
  namespace:  'admin/api'
  table_name: 'materials'
  constructor:(@$rootScope,@$http)->
    super
  collection:
    get: 'downloaded'
    get: 'incomplete'
    get: 'submitted'
    get: 'marked'
    get: 'reviewed'
    get: 'corrected'
    get: 'completed'
    post: 'sort'
    post: 'sort_recieve'

new Material()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `collection` object consists of elements with just two different keys: "get" and "post". Since each key can only map to one value, your object is reduced to:

```
  collection:
    get: 'downloaded'
    ...
    get: 'corrected'
    get: 'completed'
    post: 'sort'
    post: 'sort_recieve'
```

The solution is to make more senseful objects, for instance an array of custom objects (created using a shortcut function with a senseful name, as in the example below.).

```
class window.Restful
  constructor: ->
    _.each @collection, (obj) =>
      {action,kind} = obj
      $('.actions').append "<div>#{action} #{kind}</div>"

class Material extends Restful
  get = (action) -> {action, kind:'get'}
  post = (action) -> {action, kind:'post'}
  ...

  collection: [
    get 'downloaded'
    get 'incomplete'
    get 'submitted'
    get 'marked'
    get 'reviewed'
    get 'corrected'
    get 'completed'
    post 'sort'
    post 'sort_recieve'
  ]
```

The full result is shown at http://jsfiddle.net/Czenu/2/.